# Using JSON_TEXTCONTAINS I cannot find value ALL (oracle 12C)

Tags: json, oracle, contains

I have issue with `JSON_TEXTCONTAINS`. I am using this during search values in query but I found unexpected issue. When I try to search `json` with value ALL query does not return any values.

columns is eg: `["ALL"] or ["0123"]`

```
SELECT *
     FROM
         CUSTOM_TABLE
     WHERE JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(json_field, '$',  '[ALL]');


SELECT * FROM CUSTOM_TABLE
     WHERE JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(json_field, '$',  '[0123]'); - works
```

I tried to use also `ALL` and more combination but I do not found the reason. Also I checked forbidden words but it is not the issue

Comment: do oyu have an index an your json column. [JSON_TEXTCONTAINS Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#SQLRF56963)

Comment: I have index 
`CREATE INDEX idx_custom_field ON CUSTOM_TABLE (json_field) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
    PARAMETERS ('SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)');`

index is required in this case.

Comment: Main issue is that when I use text ALL results are 0 records :/

Comment: could be `ALL` a "keyword" or reserved word? because if i try with another one it works *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4e0a5be917bdf60a036114090961bff)*

Comment: I checked reserved words in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ccref/special-characters-in-oracle-text-queries.html#GUID-4639581C-7F65-4C9E-96CE-0A7EAA10086F and there is not ALL there.

Comment: I can agree that ALL can be keyword because similar issue is with word "AND".

Anyway when I use escaping {ALL} I get syntax error:

`ORA-29902: błąd podczas wykonywania podprogramu ODCIIndexStart()
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50900: text query parser error on line 1, column 8  
DRG-50917: escape on at end of text query string
`

Comment: here is a list with reserved words https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621

Comment: I agree that ALL is general keyword in oracle but I was confused that I can not search it using JSON_CONTAINS :/. I need to add other solution using additional table and then using standard equals method on joined table.